# Where to put the script file for autostart

Tags: linux, shell-script, rhel, autostart

I am using Linux  box which have the  the following flavour

LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.9 (Santiago)

My requirement is to start a  shell script after the server is restarted completed and all other init scripts are executed custom script need to execute For the same, I put the custom script path in the file named "/etc/rc.d/rc.local" assuming that on restart it will pickup, but after the restart, it didn't pick up on restart.

Comment: /etc/rc.d/rc.local is no longer a thing since systemd.